# Can you portably read sensitive input from the commandline?

Tags: security, posix, sh, prompt

The bash builtin `read` has a flag `-s` that prevents it from echoing whatever is being read from the commandline. After [searching opengroup.org](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) and filtering through all the *other* meanings for `read`, I still haven't found a POSIX/portable equivalent. Is there a reasonable way to do this?

In bash it's easy enough:

```
$ bash -c 'read -sp "What is your password? " password; printf "\n%s\n" "$password"'
What is your password? 
I'll never tell!
```

But in sh…

```
$ dash -c 'printf "What is your password? "; read password >/dev/null 2>&1; printf "\n%s\n" "$password"'
What is your password? I'll never tell!

I'll never tell!
```

Comment: not in sh...at least for the moment  [see here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=651446)

Comment: @bachN Thanks! The answer to my question is in there (`stty -echo`)… Do you want to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer to your question is as described in this [link](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=651446)
you can turn off by using builtin command stty

```
stty -echo
```

ps:

dont forget to save your previous settings

```
old_set=$(stty -g)
stty -echo

read -r password

stty "$old_set"
```